# Example of the use of : and/or :: in XY-pic

Tags: xy-pic

Could someone please provide an example of the use of ::, using sample code and coordinates and showing step-by step the changed content of p, c, origin, xbase, ybase, and any other pertinent variables. I can't seem to follow the example in the XY-pic reference (note 3d, page 7).
Thanks & cheers

Anyone who has tried to read xyrefer to learn how to set the origin and base knows what was being asked:  the manual is unintelligible and lacks good (any!) example that I can understand.  Here is the most basic form of the question:  How does one set the origin in xy.

I want (480,90) to be treated as (0,0).  From xyrefer, it seems I am supposed to say something like

\xy
(480,90):
(480,90)*{\bullet};
(480,100)*{\bullet};
\endxy

to get the two bullets to be placed at (0,0) and (0,10).  I get "Dimension too large".
Okay, there seems to be some point about setting the scale following the colon.  But I don't want to change the scale.   Nonetheless,  I tried replacing the bare (480,90): by

(480,90):<1pt,1pt>;

and I still get "dimension too large".

Here's what I am trying to accomplish:  my diagram lies between (480,90) at the lower left corner and (1000,280) at the upper right.  I don't want a lot of blank space below and to the left of the display:  I want to see just this window.